# PHP AES-128-CBC decryption removing XML tags

Tags: php, xml, aes

I'm trying to handle API XML response which is received as encrypted data. I use this function to decrypt it

```
function aes128_cbc_decrypt($key, $data, $iv) {
   $data = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
   $padding = ord($data[strlen($data) - 1]);
   return substr($data, 0, -$padding);
}
```

And the result is:

```
888 123671891 123 2018-12-11 123671892 1234 2018-12-11
```

But the result should be something like this

```
<Codes>
  <ServiceProviderId>888</ServiceProviderId>
  <Voucher>
    <PIN>123671891</PIN>
    <Serial>123</Serial>
    <Validity>2018-12-31</Validity>
  </Voucher>
  <Voucher>
    <PIN>123671892</PIN>
    <Serial>1234</Serial>
    <Validity>2018-01-23</Validity>
  </Voucher>
</Codes>
```

I tried to convert it into xml:

```
$oXML = new SimpleXMLElement($data);//data is the plain text before the tags
```

But I get:

```
Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 13: parser error : expected '>' 

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 13: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: Code line 1 and M 

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' 
Stack trace: #0 : SimpleXMLElement->__construct('<Codes...') #1 {main}
```

So how to edit the function to leep the tags or even convert to plain text data separated by a space to xml tags like the mentioned example?

**[Update]**

The service provider uses this command line to decrypt and extract the XML code

```
openssl enc -d -aes-128-cbc -K 2c6a3537532e2d55336f40562e3f3728 -iv 00000000000000000000000000000000 -nopad -in vouchers.aes -out vouchers.xml
```

I get this warning

```
Warning: mcrypt_decrypt(): The IV parameter must be as long as the blocksize
```

Would it be the issue?

**[Update2]**

New encrypted data

```
ï—®B}Õ]µåú‚2    |mE!ˆNÃìUí7“WãóZÍ? mn­Â`×ƒ«âQÅö÷õuh8ïBÈÏõ:SÔ+Ä«¬Y¦¯9U¦Ó AûûÒœïŽ tsx Ñèµ4ÍC„÷ËÄùy¼Mú‹ø‘Ú‘Êÿ*‘äœ£ç‡Œ?5Í¹¯B¾éó|•VÖ¨-pÃñ6p‚Ï>Ü­1Ž%Ò‰WœÌ~¶Î¬í#¸)i²ºøq+ÊÏ'šþ!_5ˆ¨I®ßØSe°„¶Þp~´~ÀLíQ@ wbN6'è‘Ô5Ë”õI©Üp¨b¦ùãmÁ~C•Wí>äúÕA@ƒjãDÎÐË]Çt<-Ù³{!ú®SÅÄ#…"üJíûEÒœJ·¶žÒ\y@I»€5ˆ§p=”%åÔa›%ÏgÍ¤â2u[>µ½–ƒRÈ
```

And the result should be

```
<Codes>
  <ServiceProviderId>666</ServiceProviderId>
  <Voucher>
    <PIN>123456789000001</PIN>
    <Serial>1234567890001</Serial>
    <Validity>2013-12-11</Validity>
  </Voucher>
  <Voucher>
    <PIN>123456789000002</PIN>
    <Serial>1234567890002</Serial>
    <Validity>2013-12-11</Validity>
 </Voucher>
</Codes>
```

But when I echo the decryption function I get:

```
666 123456789000001 1234567890001 2013-12-11 123456789000002 1234567890002 2013-12-11
```

And when I try to use "SimpleXMLElement" I get the warnings above.

Comment: Why do you think that the encryption breaks the XML file? Have you thoroughly checked the raw input and output?

Comment: The decryption result must be the same as the XML code and I checked the encrypted data with the service provider and it's correct

Comment: And how did you check the decrypted output?

Comment: I didn't as I get that plain text not XML. Can you help with this?

Comment: Why didn't you check the output? How did you determine that something was removed?

Comment: Post updated. As I mentioned the output must be XML. The data encoded before being sent to me is XML so the output will be the same.

Comment: _“And the result is:”_ - _where_ exactly? If you are viewing this in a document that gets output by PHP with the default text/html content-type header, then nothing was actually removed, and you are only having trouble interpreting what you are seeing correctly …

Comment: It's a PHP file that handles the encrypted code extracted from the XML response.

Comment: can you update input `data` which you are passing `encrypt` function

Comment: updated with the encrypted data and result.

Comment: There's no reason for the tags to be removed unless the service provider already removed them. Where are you echoing the output to? If it's to an HTML page it will hide the tags. Try echoing into a textarea.

Comment: If you see an error message of SimpleXML, the XML is malformed. According to the very first stacktrace, it starts with the XML tags - but most probably, the cryptic stuff you do with that `$padding` and the substr remove stuff from the decrypted string. What happens if you remove that?

Comment: Thanks @Nico Haase removing the padding and substr process solved the issue I just return data and it's working. You can add it as an answer to accept it. Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we found out during chatting in the comment section, the problem was removing some bytes at the end which were misinterpreted as a padding. Through removing these bytes, the resulting string could not get parsed through `new SimpleXMLElement($data)`

By removing the padding-related code, leaving only a simple decryption through `mcrypt_decrypt`, everything went fine